# in Vb6 and c# how do I have multiple of a string

Tags: c#, vb6

Is there a single command that replicates a string into multiples of that string or character. Sql has replicate which can replicate a space for instance into many:

```
replicate(' ', 10000) -- will make 10k spaces.
```

Is there a similiar command in vb6 and c#?

Comment: LOL, yeah I am using that too, but I am old school.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To repeat an actual string, not just one character *(code is the same for C# and VB.Net)*:

```
//Repeat "asd" 100 times
String.Join("", Enumerable.Repeat("asd", 100).ToArray())
```

Comment: Note: the `.ToArray()` call is not necessary in .Net 4.0, as `String.Join()` now takes an `IEnumerable<string>`

Comment: Nice.  That seems to work for strings.  This one does too: new String(new char[] {' ', 'X', 'O'}, 0, 33332)

Comment: Enumerable.Repeat<String>("asd", 100).ToString(); // this works in .net 4.0

Comment: @RetroCoder: Actually, neither of those will work.  Try running them for yourself to see why :)

Comment: I need to use join... ie Enumerable.Repeat<String>("abc", 100).Join(something goes in here... to join all the arrays together.

Comment: got it :) : Console.WriteLine(String.Join("",Enumerable.Repeat<String>("asd", 100)));

Answer (score 15):

In C#:

```
string s = new string(' ', 10000);
```

In VB.NET:

```
Dim s = New String(" ", 10000)
```

In VB6:

```
s = String$(10000, " ")
```

Comment: Should be noted that the C# code only works with characters, not strings.

Comment: Exact, it uses char notation(' ') contrary to the VB6 and VB.NET code that uses string notation (" ")

Comment: You can also use `Space$(10000)` in VB6.

Comment: Yeah, forgot that one, but Space$ is only to make spaces though

Comment: The VB.NET code also only works with a character, not a string. It's only if you have strict mode off that you can use a string, which then will be implicitly converted into a character. Use `New String(" "C, 10000)` to work with strict mode on.

Comment: You can also do s = String$(10000, n) where n is the ascii number of the character you want to replicate.